Is every set of 4 points chosen on a sphere cospherical in all cases?
Are every set of 4 points on a sphere cospherical in all cases ? I need to do this to solve a larger problem. So if we have a sphere and get 4 random points, can we draw a sphere where all of them lie ? Thank you so much!

No! How can you draw a circle through four points, unless they are in the same plane?

EDIT: Since the title of the question has been edited, it is somewhat unfortunate that this answer starts with the word "No". It is left to the reader to properly recontextualize it.
No. Three points define a $2$-plane, the intersection of which with a sphere is always circular. But a fourth point need not lie in the same plane. Four non-coplanar points do however uniquely define a sphere.

But if we know that these 4 points are coplanar it still holds?

the intersection of an $n$-plane with an $n$-sphere is always an $n-1$-sphere. (unless the plane is tangent to the sphere)

No i mean if we know that the 4 points on the sphere are coplanar are they concyclic in this case?

read my comment again, it answers this question.

So the answer is yes? Im not fluent in English this is why I ask you again...Thanks so much for your answer!

you mention that your points are coplanar, meaning they all lie on the intersection of the plane with the sphere. In the case of a $2$-sphere and a $2$-plane, the intersection is a $2-1 = 1$-sphere, commonly known as a circle. so the answer is yes.

@paulina, four non-coplanar points define a sphere uniquely. Four coplanar points don't.

@TonyK of course. I meant to imply this, but I can see how it is not obvious. I will edit.
